# How can I store a select path in a variable?

Tags: xslt

I have a simple XML file:

```
<employees>
    <employee name="Alice" salary="40000" bonus="1000" />
    <employee name="Bob" salary="50000" bonus="2000" />
    <employee name="Clarisse" salary="60000" bonus="3000" />
    <employee name="David" salary="70000" bonus="4000" />
</employees>
```

And I have an XSLT file that simply rearranges the data a little and provides a sum of the salaries:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

    <xsl:template match="employees">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="employee" />
            <sum>
                <name>Total</name>
                <salary>
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(employee/@salary)"/>
                </salary>
            </sum>
        </root>        
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="employee">
        <item>
            <name><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></name>
            <salary><xsl:value-of select="@salary"/></salary>
        </item>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My question concerns the salary data.  Suppose in the future I want to replace the salary information with the bonus information.  To do this, I'd have to make two edits: I'd have to replace `sum(employee/@salary)` with `sum(employee/@bonus)` and `<xsl:value-of select="@salary"/>` with `<xsl:value-of select="@bonus"/>`.  (I'm ignoring the node names for now `<salary>`).

Is there a way to use an xsl:variable or an xsl:key or something else to store the `@salary` parts above so that I only need to make one edit instead of two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:param name="sumAttr" select="'salary'" />

    <xsl:template match="employees">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="employee" />
            <sum>
                <name>Total</name>
                <xsl:element name="{$sumAttr}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(employee/@*[name() = $sumAttr])"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </sum>
        </root>        
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="employee">
        <item>
            <name><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></name>
            <xsl:element name="{$sumAttr}">
                <xsl:value-of select="@*[name() = $sumAttr]"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </item>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The `<xsl:param>` defaults to `'salary'` but you can set it programmatically.

XSLT 1.0 cannot evaluate strings as XPath at run-time. In other words, passing in an XPath expression will not work. The simple problem you have demonstrated can be worked around as shown above.

More complex scenarios are thinkable as well - e.g. using template modes, different XSL imports or even a complex script-based solution (since you made reference to the `msxsl` namespace).

Comment: This will carry some penalty in terms of performance, won't it?

Comment: Negligible. Try it,  measure it and decide if a few hundreds of a second of difference  is something worth worrying about.

Comment: Perfect.  Including the <xsl:element> node which I didn't know about beforehand.